# Wordpress API - Getting just post content

Tags: api

I am trying to get the content from a wordpress page into a file. Is there a way to do this with the API? When I try to use the API, it returns all the content in html instead of text, and I just want the text (and maybe a way to try to remember which pictures were with each page but that's not as important)

"my-site.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages" gives

```
"content": {
"rendered": "<h1 style=\"text-align:center;whi ..."
```

is there a way to get the content, not html, in an unrendered format?

I have tried setting the context to "edit" through query params (?context=edit) and also passed through this wrapper along with basic password authentication: https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth. The wrapper works fine but whenever I try to set the context to edit instead of view, it gives me a 401 error. Any ideas what to try?

EDIT: making request like

```
const wp = new WPAPI({
    endpoint: 'https://example.com/wp-json',
    username: 'editor',
    password: 'password'
});

wp.param("context", "edit")
  .pages().then(res => console.log(res));
```

where editor and password are the username and password I personally use to login to wordpress

Comment: It's impossible to say why you'd be getting a 401 without seeing how you're making an authenticated request.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Updated question with that code